# R convert following format to date class

Tags: r, date, format

I have a data frame consist of two columns date and Text. The format of date is somewhat typical as `Jan 09 05:44:30 +0000 2015`. Now i want to convert this date in to format as `01/09/2015 05:44:30` or `Jan/09/2015 05:44:30`. I did some efforts on single date and it worked fine but same failed on whole date column. Please help .
 I tried as such way :

```
p <- "Jan 09 05:44:30 +0000 2015"
p <- sub("Jan","01",p)
p1 <- strsplit(p," ")
p2 <- unlist(p1)
append(p2,p2[5], after=2)
```

I have data frame which looks like :

```
        Text                          Date
  "...some text ....."        Jan 09 05:44:30 +0000 2015
  "...some text ....."        Jan 09 05:44:30 +0000 2015
  "...some text ....."        Jan 09 05:44:30 +0000 2015
  "...some text ....."        Jan 09 05:44:30 +0000 2015
```

and I want it as:

```
       Text                          Date
  "...some text ....."        01/09/2015 05:44:30
  "...some text ....."        01/09/2015 05:44:30
  "...some text ....."        01/09/2015 05:44:30
  "...some text ....."        01/09/2015 05:44:30
```

Comment: Would you edit your question to include what worked with the single dates?

Comment: Try `p <- sub("Jan","01",p);strftime(as.POSIXct(p,format="%m %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y"),"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`.

Comment: There is no need to first replace "Jan" by "01" (which will become rather tedious if you have different months in your date). Simply change nicola's suggestion to `strftime(as.POSIXct(p,format="%b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y"),format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`. `%b` is the placeholder for "Abbreviated month name in the current locale". So, as the documentation states, this will only work if the month abbreviations match your locale settings.

Comment: Is `+0000` always the same? There must be a reason why it was included in the datetimes to begin with.

Comment: @Roland Well i dont know the exact reason but answer is yes. +0000 always the same. Actually the data is downloaded from facebook using py.

Comment: It's probably timezone information which can be parsed.

Comment: @Roland It seems. Coz when i tried removing that using sub and gsub only 0000 had been removed and + remained.

Comment: There is no need for any `gsub`ing. Study `help("strptime")` carefully.

Comment: I will surely check that sir. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Study `help("strptime")` to learn how to create the `format` string.

```
p <- "Jan 09 05:44:30 +0000 2015"
as.POSIXct(p, format="%b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz="GMT")
#[1] "2015-01-09 05:44:30 GMT"
```

This gives you a datetime object (and is of course vectorized). Use the `format` function as necessary for creating output strings with other formats if you must.